# How to handle foreign key while importing data from Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, foreign-keys, sql-import-wizard

I have raw data in an Excel sheet. I develop a database in SQL Server with foreign key constraints, now I want to import data from my Excel sheet into my SQL Server database (with multiple tables with foreign key constraints).

Please guide me how can I handle foreign key while importing data into my database? I am new to SQL Server database, any tutorial link will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on a data which is being exported using Excel. I suggest you following approach.

1. Dump the data into a intermediate table without any constraint.
2. Validate the data before moving to the main table. For this you can use `where exists` clause to check if the data is present in the foreign key table or not.
3. Records which are failed in validation, you can report them back to the user.

Comment: can you please provide me any helpful link or tutorial?

Comment: Did you checked this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQL Server Integration Services, a lookup transformation would do the work for you. This is an example:
http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/ssis-lookup-transformation-example.php

We also offer an Excel Add-In to import and update data in SQL Server from Excel. 
It has the possibility to create drop-down lists in Excel for foreign key relations. The user will then select a text item in Excel (fetched from the foreign key table) and the corresponding key value will be inserted into the table in SQL Server.
More details are available here: https://sqlspreads.com